# Syslinux , what does '--' do?

Tags: syslinux

What does the '--' do in a normal syslinux config ? I used to see "quiet" after that , but don't know why.

Here's an example from Ubuntu 12.04:

```
label install
    menu label ^Install
    menu default
    kernel ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
    append vga=788 initrd=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz -- quiet
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Many commandline tools take arguments. There are one-letter, short, arguments and ... long arguments. They change the default behaviour of such a tool.

Short arguments are prefixed with a single dash `-`
Long arguments are prefixed with a double dash `--`

Short arguments can be combined into `ls -l -t -r` is the same as `ls -ltr`.
Long arguments need to be distinguished from combined singles, and to do that, a long argument is prefixed with a double dash `ls -l -t --reverse` or `ls -lt --reverse`

Long arguments are easier to remember, short ones faster to type.

Most commands have a manual page which explains these arguments in detail. Eg. `man ls` for the manual page of the ls command which I used in my examples above.

Comment: I believe the original question is about the exact sequence `--` in a *configuration* file, not the command line. GNU `getopt(1)` and `getopt(3)` use `--` to signal the end of options. Everything after it is interpreted as an argument. E.g. `grep -- -E file` looks for the string `-E` in `file` (even though `-E` is a `grep` option). This could be what's happening here if syslinux (ab)uses `getopt(3)` to parse its configuration files. (or if it simulates the behaviour)

Comment: @Alexios maybe you should put that as an answer

Comment: I would, but it's not really an answer. I know the conventional semantics of `--` but I can't answer the question *in spirit* because I don't know what the heck it's doing in a SysLinux `append` line. :)

Answer (score 14):

Anything that is passed after the '--' are appended to the default 
options for the installed system. Everything before the '--' is only 
used by the installer itself.

Source: http://www.syslinux.org/archives/2009-December/013978.html

When the installation is finished you can find the options in the `/etc/default/grub` file at the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.
If you edit this line you wille have to type `update-grub` so the content of this line is installed in the boot loader (used when launching the Linux kernel).

Comment: +1 Though not nearly as verbose, this is the actual answer to the question being asked.

Comment: I added a few more infos. This answer now seems fine to me.